# MDX SUM function and NULL values

Tags: mdx, ssas-2008

I'm trying to create some reports for Team Foundation Server 2010 using underlying SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services database. The cube 'Team System' is the one that comes with TFS 2010 Reporting.

My problem is. I tried to use StateChangeCount measure of FactWorkItemHistory.
For some periods of time there are no work item state changes but there are other changes.
So we have some fact rows having NULL StateChangeCount as presented later.

The State Change Count measure sometimes produces values of 0 even if the underlying fact rows contain NULL values. This measure is defined as SUM on [FactWorkItemHistory].[StateChangeCount]. Is it by design that SUM of NULLS returns 0 or am I missing something?
The problematic period is 2013-03-01 (March) and 2013-05-02 (May).

```
SELECT
  [DateSK],
  COUNT(*) AS COUNT,
  SUM([StateChangeCount]) AS SUM
FROM
      [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[FactWorkItemHistory]
WHERE
      [WorkItemSK] IN (SELECT [WorkItemSK] FROM [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[DimWorkItem]     WHERE [System_WorkItemType] = 'Bug')
GROUP BY
  [DateSK]
```

the output is:

```
DateSK                  COUNT SUM
---------------------------------------
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 13    7
2012-03-01 00:00:00.000 2     NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 60    2
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 16    NULL
2013-05-06 00:00:00.000 9     9
```

The query:

```
SELECT
  [DateSK],
  [StateChangeCount]
FROM
      [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[FactWorkItemHistory]
WHERE
      [WorkItemSK] IN (SELECT [WorkItemSK] FROM [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[DimWorkItem] WHERE [System_WorkItemType] = 'Bug')
ORDER BY   
      [DateSK]
```

gives:

```
DateSK                  StateChangeCount
---------------------------------------
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 1
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 NULL
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 NULL
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 1
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 NULL
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 1
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 NULL
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 1
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 NULL
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 1
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 NULL
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 1
2011-05-05 00:00:00.000 1
2012-03-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-03-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 1
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 1
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2012-09-28 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-02 00:00:00.000 NULL
2013-05-06 00:00:00.000 1
2013-05-06 00:00:00.000 1
2013-05-06 00:00:00.000 1
2013-05-06 00:00:00.000 1
2013-05-06 00:00:00.000 1
2013-05-06 00:00:00.000 1
2013-05-06 00:00:00.000 1
2013-05-06 00:00:00.000 1
2013-05-06 00:00:00.000 1
```

And finally MDX queries:

```
SELECT
 NON EMPTY { [Measures].[State Change Count] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY { ([Date].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS * [Work Item].[System_State].    [System_State].ALLMEMBERS ) }
ON ROWS FROM (
            SELECT (
                  { [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Bug] }
                       )
          ON COLUMNS FROM [Team System])
            WHERE ( [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Bug] )
```

results in:

```
                              StateChangeCount
---------------------------------------------
2011-05-05  Assigned          4
2011-05-05  For verification  2
2011-05-05  In progress       1
2012-03-01  Assigned          0
2012-09-28  Assigned          2
2013-05-02  Assigned          0
2013-05-06  Assigned          9
```

While

```
SELECT
 NON EMPTY { [Measures].[State Change Count] } ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY { ([Date].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS * [Work Item].[System_State].    [System_State].ALLMEMBERS ) }
ON ROWS FROM (
        SELECT (
              { [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Bug] }
                   )
      ON COLUMNS FROM [Team System])
        WHERE ( [Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Bug] )
```

is:

```
                 State Change Count
------------------------------------
May 2011          7
June 2011         (null)
July 2011         (null)
August 2011       (null)
September 2011    (null)
October 2011      (null)
November 2011     (null)
December 2011     (null)
January 2012      (null)
February 2012     (null)
March 2012        0
April 2012        (null)
May 2012          (null)
June 2012         (null)
July 2012         (null)
August 2012       (null)
September 2012    2
October 2012      (null)
November 2012     (null)
December 2012     (null)
January 2013      (null)
February 2013     (null)
March 2013        (null)
April 2013        (null)
May 2013          9
June 2013         (null)
July 2013         (null)
August 2013       (null)
Unknown           (null)
```

I can see that for problematic periods there are some fact rows but containing other work item data changes. I would expect that these items should not pollute the results especially for SUM. For COUNT, agreed, seeing a value of zero is fine but not for SUM.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried to use AGGREGATE instead of SUM?